# why no backshifting here?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

In April 1912 Rose DeWitt Bukater boarded the Titanic, a liner that was travelling from Southampton to New York. She was with her mother and her snob fiancé Caledon Hockley. Rose was a rich woman who had met her future husband at university. However, Cal was not what she had expected and she felt helplessly trapped. She thought  of killing herself by jumping from the ship, but then a passenger travelling in third-class, Jack Dawson, convinced her not to do it. Rose told everyone she **was trying**  to see the propellers when she suddenly slipped  and that if it hadn't been for Jack, she would have fallen into the sea.

Why is it not  "had been trying" or "had tried", why the writer did not backshift? Is it because the telling happened just after her suicide attempt and the relation between these 2 actions(to try  committing  suicide and to tell ) are crystal clear without past perfect .

Comment: Because English speakers often do not bother with the so-called "past perfect" when the temporal relationships are clear without it.

Comment: -1 for not attributing the source.

Comment: What @colin said. Besides which, backshifting is *optional*, not obligatory, even to strict pedants.

Answer (score 0):

The simple past tense can very often be substituted for the past perfect or past perfect progressive in English, especially in casual communication. In some contexts, using one or the other helps remove ambiguity, but in most cases the meaning is entirely clear no matter which one you pick, and native English speakers often gravitate towards the one that requires fewer words.

Which is to say, this sentence could be written as "she was trying to see the propellers when" or "she had been trying to see the propellers when", and both are perfectly acceptable.